# NSIS ReadCustomerdata no data error

Tags: python, nsis

```
; Example:
;   Push "CUSTDATA:"
;   Call ReadCustomerData
;   Pop $1
;   StrCmp $1 "" 0 +3
;   MessageBox MB_OK "No data found"
;   Abort
;   MessageBox MB_OK "Customer data: '$1'"
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include StrLoc.nsi
Section
   Push "CUSTDATA:"
   Call ReadCustomerData
   Pop $1
   StrCmp $1 "" 0 +3
   MessageBox MB_OK "No data found"
   Abort
   MessageBox MB_OK "Customer data: '$1'"
SectionEnd
Function ReadCustomerData
  ; arguments
  Exch $R1            ; customer data magic value
  ; locals
  Push $1             ; file name or (later) file handle
  Push $2             ; current trial offset
  Push $3             ; current trial string (which will match $R1 when customer data is found)
  Push $4             ; length of $R1
  Push $5             ; half length of $R1
  Push $6             ; first half of $R1
  Push $7             ; tmp

  FileOpen $1 $EXEPATH r

; change 4096 here to, e.g., 2048 to scan just the last 2Kb of EXE file
  IntOp $2 0 - 4096

  StrLen $4 $R1

  IntOp $5 $4 / 2
  StrCpy $6 $R1 $5


loop:
  FileSeek $1 $2 END
  FileRead $1 $3 $4
  StrCmpS $3 $R1 found

  ${StrLoc} $7 $3 $6 ">"
  StrCmpS $7 "" NotFound
    IntCmp $7 0 FoundAtStart
      ; We can jump forwards to the position at which we found the partial match
      IntOp $2 $2 + $7
      IntCmp $2 0 loop loop
FoundAtStart:
    ; We should make progress
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
    IntCmp $2 0 loop loop
NotFound:
    ; We can safely jump forward half the length of the magic
    IntOp $2 $2 + $5
    IntCmp $2 0 loop loop

  StrCpy $R1 ""
  goto fin

found:
  IntOp $2 $2 + $4
  FileSeek $1 $2 END
  FileRead $1 $3
  StrCpy $R1 $3

fin:
  Pop $7
  Pop $6
  Pop $5
  Pop $4
  Pop $3
  Pop $2
  Pop $1
  Exch $R1
FunctionEnd
```

when i run this file i am no data found.My question is 
1 .how do i edit that 
2. and retrive the data.what kind of data i can push and how.

3. also i want push the data using python how do i achieve that
4. how do edit exe file using python
   first two question are important for me

Thanks a ton in advance
Kudos to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could it find data when you have not added any? You can add any data you want but the `ReadCustomerData` function cannot handle binary data, only a string. You can use any method you have available to write the data, it just has to start with `CUSTDATA:`:

```
makensis Test.nsi
>>"Test.exe" echo.CUSTDATA:Hello World
start Test.exe
```

Comment: Using the above example I used the command
makensis test.nsi this create a test.exe file
then in cmd ran the command
"test.exe" echo.CUSTDATA:Hello World
exe automatically start and it say no data found i think my above code is worng i dont know where it is breaking

Comment: You need the `>>` part to echo to the file. You can also just use a hex editor to append data.

Comment: I just see weird number when i open exe file hex editor. I am new to this please if you have a example explain here Anders

Comment: If you are unable to learn the basics about binary files and hex editors then maybe this is not the right project for you. ReadCustomerData just requires you to append some ASCII data to the end of the generated .exe

Comment: how can i do this in python

Comment: I just got it i was able to do this. thanks for the help. is their a way to edit this data using python.

Comment: You should ask a new question that is python specific.